# Angular 6 on App Engine - Error 500 on page refresh

Tags: angular, google-app-engine

Angular 6 app on App Engine. Navigation on the app works fine but if I reload a page (whichever page) it displays the following error:

```
Error: Server Error
```

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

It is working absolutely fine locally though. So I figured it might come from the app.yaml which is as follows:

```
runtime: nodejs10

env_variables:
  environment: "--prod"

handlers:
- url: /assets
  static_dir: dist/assets
- url: /
  secure: always
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/.*
- url: /(.*\.js)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/.*\.js
- url: /(.*\.css)
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  static_files: dist/\1
  mime_type: text/css
  upload: dist/.*\.css
```

Error produced by App Engine:
`"logMessage": "The request failed because the instance could not start successfully"`

Any idea what is happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Error 500 is not a client-side error, please check your API which is sending the wrong message. or you find where logical error

Comment: @Shohel that's why I tagged the question as google-app-engine too and provided the app.yaml. Figured that someone might help on this part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you're not using `#` in the route URL. As the application is deployed, it's treating the route as a file and may be seraching for it.

I'm not sure this is the issue. once try this in your `app-routing.module.ts`

```
<!--app-routing.module.ts -->
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })]
```